# App Permission (appinv.aspx) /app/manifest cannot contain text

Tags: 2013, workflow, permissions, sharepoint-server, app

I got the problem, that if I want to grant the Workflow to trust (/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx), I get the following error:

*The element 'AppPermissionRequests' in Namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest' cannot contain text. The list with the possible elements was expected: 'AppPermissionRequest' in Namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest'.*

I copied the Workflow App-Identifier and the XML correctly. And UPS, Workflow and Service Bus Services are running.

Any idea? I'm stuck here :(

Here the details (Correlation-ID):

```
Timestamp               Process                                     TID     Area                            Category                        EventID Level       Message     Correlation
03/20/2015 15:41:19.70  w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (POST:http://sp13:80/jourmix/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx)  e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.70  w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium  Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|fuep\spadmin, ClaimsCount=27 e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.70  w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium  Site=/  e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.71  w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           00000   High    UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.    bei Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContainer(SPFileStreamStore spfs, ILockBytes ilb, Boolean copyOnFirstWrite, Boolean disposeIlb)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.SetInputLockBytes(SPFileInfo& fileInfo, SqlSession session, PrefetchResult prefetchResult)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocumentRowset(Guid databaseId, SqlSession session, SPFileStreamManager spfstm, Object[] metadataRow, SPRowset contentRowset, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& d... e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.71* w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           00000   High    ...bres)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermM...  e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.71* w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           00000   High    ...ask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String...  e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.71* w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           00000   High    ...& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwV...  e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.71* w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           00000   High    ...ersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebPartPageContent(Uri pageUrl, Int32 pageVersion, PageView requestedView, HttpContext context, Boolean forRender, Boolean includeHidden, Boolean mainFileRequest, Boolean fetchDependencyInformation, Boolean& ghostedPage, String& siteRoot, Guid& siteId, Int64&...  e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.71* w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           00000   High    ... bytes, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, Byte& level, Object& buildDependencySetData, UInt32& dependencyCount, Object& buildDependencies, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& redirectUrl, Boolean& ObjectIsList, Guid& listId)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.FetchWebPartPageInformationForInit(HttpContext context, SPWeb spweb, Boolean mainFileRequest, String path, Boolean impersonate, Boolean& isAppWeb, Boolean& fGhostedPage, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, SPFileLevel& spLevel, String& masterPageUrl, String& customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl, String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId, Object& buildDependencySetData, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initi...  e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.71* w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           00000   High    ...alState, String& siteRoot, String& redirectUrl, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, Boolean& objectIsList, Guid& listId, Int64& bytes)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetWebPartPageData(HttpContext context, String path, Boolean throwIfFileNotFound)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String virtualPath)     bei System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     bei System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     bei System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBu...  e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.71* w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           00000   High    ...ildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     bei System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     bei System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection)     bei System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage()     bei System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()     bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     bei System.Web.UI.Page.Proce...  e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.71* w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           00000   High    ...ssRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     bei System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     bei System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     bei System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     bei System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     bei System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     bei System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObject...  e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.71* w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           00000   High    ...sPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     bei System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     bei System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     bei System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     bei System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     bei System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleDa...  e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.71* w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           00000   High    ...ta, Int32 flags) e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.71  w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           aiv4w   Medium  Spent 0 ms to bind 29783 byte file stream   e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.76  w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           General                         agsqn   High    App permission validation failed System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException: Das Element 'AppPermissionRequests' in Namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest' darf keinen Text enthalten. Erwartet wurde die Liste der möglichen Elemente: 'AppPermissionRequest' in Namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest'.     bei System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(XmlSchemaValidationException e, XmlSeverityType severity)     bei System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(String code, String[] args)     bei System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessReaderEvent()     bei System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()     bei System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)     bei System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom... e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.76* w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           General                         agsqn   High    ...(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)     bei System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppPermissionProvider.ValidateAppPermissionRequests(String permissionXml, Action`2 processPermissionXml)    e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.76  w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8nca    Medium  Application error when access /_layouts/15/appinv.aspx, Error=Das Element 'AppPermissionRequests' in Namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest' darf keinen Text enthalten. Erwartet wurde die Liste der möglichen Elemente: 'AppPermissionRequest' in Namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest'.   bei System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(XmlSchemaValidationException e, XmlSeverityType severity)     bei System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(String code, String[] args)     bei System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessReaderEvent()     bei System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()     bei System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)     bei System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOpt... e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.76* w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8nca    Medium  ...ions o)     bei System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppPermissionProvider.ValidateAppPermissionRequests(String permissionXml, Action`2 processPermissionXml) e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.78  w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException: Das Element 'AppPermissionRequests' in Namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest' darf keinen Text enthalten. Erwartet wurde die Liste der möglichen Elemente: 'AppPermissionRequest' in Namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest'.    bei System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(XmlSchemaValidationException e, XmlSeverityType severity)     bei System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(String code, String[] args)     bei System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessReaderEvent()     bei System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()     bei System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)     bei System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)     b... e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.78* w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...ei System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppPermissionProvider.ValidateAppPermissionRequests(String permissionXml, Action`2 processPermissionXml)  e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.78  w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High    Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Eine Ausnahme vom Typ "System.Web.HttpUnhandledException" wurde ausgelöst. ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Das Element 'AppPermissionRequests' in Namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest' darf keinen Text enthalten. Erwartet wurde die Liste der möglichen Elemente: 'AppPermissionRequest' in Namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest'. ---> System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException: Das Element 'AppPermissionRequests' in Namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest' darf keinen Text enthalten. Erwartet wurde die Liste der möglichen Elemente: 'AppPermissionRequest' in Namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/201... e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.78* w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High    ...2/app/manifest'.     bei System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(XmlSchemaValidationException e, XmlSeverityType severity)     bei System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(String code, String[] args)     bei System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessReaderEvent()     bei System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()     bei System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)     bei System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)     bei System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppPermissionProvider.ValidateAppPermissionRequests(String permissionXml, Action`2 processPermissionXml)     --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Admi...  e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.78* w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High    ...nistration.SPAppPermissionProvider.ValidateAppPermissionRequests(String permissionXml, Action`2 processPermissionXml)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppPermissionProvider.ValidateAppPermissionRequestsAndExtractAppInfo(String permissionXml)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AppAuthorizePageBase.BtnCreate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)     bei System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)     bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     bei System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)     bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean incl...  e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.78* w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High    ...udeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     bei System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     bei System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.86  w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           Upgrade                         aiaih   High    [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] desiredVersion: {0}    e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.87  w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           General                         aat87   Monitorable     e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27

03/20/2015 15:41:19.89  w3wp.exe (SP13:0x1750)                      0x1164  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:http://sp13:80/jourmix/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx)). Ausführungszeit=194,343513760386   e79cf49c-8915-a0ac-ea91-14f8e51c4d27
```

Comment: Could you please share your permissions Request XML.

Comment: I found the problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem. It was the XML snippet :O

I did it always exactly like this:

```
<AppPermissionRequests>

<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />

</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Instead I had to do it like this (everything together, NO SPACES, NO BRAKES):

```
<AppPermissionRequests><AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" /></AppPermissionRequests>
```

After that, the "Trust Workflow" dialog showed up and I was able to finish it.

Keep in mind that the XML is a little different if you wanna have access to the whole site collection (http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2014/06/19/gotcha-on-sharepoint-designer-workflows-in-app-step/).

Comment: I had no problem putting in xml on seperate lines - likely you had some invalid character or other formatting problem. Did you copy this directly from web page/word document - always do from notepad or similar to see whats going on.

Comment: no invalid chars, maybe there was a hidden space or brake somewhere. I have had since then several new SharePoint farms to build and never had an issue again with all in one line. So I go with that :)

Comment: Read up on Cargo Cult Programming - I *guarantee* you that the problem was not separate lines, it was some other invalid char that you deleted when moving to one line.